Script to find multiple files and update their timestamps by a second
I'm trying to create an interactive script that lets me choose a start date and time, then recurse into the present directory/subdirectories, find all flac audio files, sorted by directory/subdirectories/filename and then update the timestamp by 1 second starting from the initial user input start date.
#!/bin/bash

# Description: change mtime using touch with time offset

# get starting date and time
read -p "Starting date and time (ex. 2012-03-22 22:00:05): " start_date

# convert to unix timestamp
start() {
    date -d "${start_date}" +%s
}

# find all flac files inside a directory 
flac() {
    find . -type f -name "*.flac" | sort
}

for file in $flac; do
  touch -d @$start "$flac"
  # increment by 1 second
  $start=$(start + 1)
done


(a) You don't actually ask a question, specify what shell you use, or say what the problem is with your work so far. (b) You have a function start which you don't call, but has a name conflict with a variable. (c) You have a function flac but you don't call that, you treat it like a plain variable.

Use shellcheck to syntax-check scripts. You can use this on the web, or download it. It has a page of hints for each error code (of which you trigger four).

There are few points to consider:
You do not need function for start, you need variable. Do not forget you later do math with this. So your lines:
start() {
    date -d "${start_date}" +%s
}

should be
start=$(date -d "${start_date}" +%s)

You do not need function to get list of files, you can incorporate it in the loop. Something like this can do the work:
while read flac; do
  touch -d @$start "$flac"
  # increment by 1 second
  start=$(($start + 1))
done < <(find . -type f -name "*.flac" | sort)


Any of ((++start)) ((start+=1)) and start=$((start + 1)) serve to increment a variable in Bash. Inside ((..)), any non-numeric word is assumed to be a variable name. Also, shellcheck nags that read -r is advised.
